# how to check if B isn't betwenn A and B

Tags: list, prolog

i have a question, how can i make a program that says that given a list, B is not in the middle of A and C? i can suppose that betwwen A and C is only one position..

so:

```
?-not_between(A,B,C,[A,D,C,B]
true
?-not_between(A,B,C,[B,A,D,C]
true
?-not_between(A,B,C,[B,C,D,A]
true
?-not_between(A,B,C,[C,D,A,B]
true
```

like:

i've done one program that makes the opposite( check if B is betwenn A and C).

my code for between is:

```
bet(S1,S2,S3,[S1,S2,S3|_]).
bet(S1,S2,S3,[S3,S2,S1|_]).
bet(S1,S2,S3,[_|R]):-entre(S1,S2,S3,R).
```

and i want to make an program named not_between..

but i don't know how

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the program you already have:

```
\+ is_betwenn(List, A, B, C).
```

`\+` is sometimes written `not`. Check your implementation.

With this implementation (note the small correction!):

```
bet(S1,S2,S3,[S1,S2,S3|_]).
bet(S1,S2,S3,[S3,S2,S1|_]).
bet(S1,S2,S3,[_|R]) :- bet(S1,S2,S3,R).

not_bet(S1,S2,S3,List) :- \+ bet(S1,S2,S3,List).

?- not_bet(1,2,3,[1,3,2]).
true.
?- bet(1,2,3,[1,3,2]).
false.
?- not_bet(1,2,3,[3,2,1]).
false.
?- bet(1,2,3,[3,2,1]).
true ;
false.
```

I don't see the problem....

Comment: `(\+)/1` is prescribed by the Prolog ISO standard, whereas `not/1` isn't. So, you should use `(\+)/1` for portability.

Comment: i've used:
notBet(S1,S2,S3,_):- \+ bet(S1,S2,S3,_).  

and evaluate as:
?- notBet(1,2,3,[1,3,2]).
false